# psql: error: connection to server at "localhost"

Tags: postgresql, windows

Let me first mention I don't have admin privilege on my PC, So I could not install PostgreSQL with the normal process. I just download the binary files from here enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries,
and added it to environment variable paths.

My problem when I try to start a new server from pgAdmin it gives me the below error.

```
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused 
(0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused 
(0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I searched a lot for a solution

The first recommendation I got is to restart postgress from windows services but I couldn't find it.

Second recommendation was to edit the psogress config file but also I can't find it at all they say that I can find it in the main directory of postgress.

Comment: Did you  run `initdb` and registered a Windows service and started that? Just downloading and "adding it to the path" isn't enough to install a Postgres server

Comment: no I didn't can you give me a link with the steps, noting that when I ran psql -v it gave me the version of it normally

Comment: this is where postgress isntalled in my machine C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\pgsql

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html

Comment: `psql -v` gives you the version of `psql.exe` it does not connect to a Postgres server.

Comment: This working perfectly. I don't know how can I thank you :))